# Are there any references to Halley's Comet in the Hindu scriptures?

Tags: belief, scripture

Are there any references to [Halley's Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_Comet) in the Hindu scriptures? If there are, then in what perspective is the comet depicted as?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly there is no direct reference to it because in ancient times Halley's comet was not known by that name. But there is mention of a big comet that was seen in the sky during the Mahabharata war:

> धूमकेतुर महाघॊरः पुष्यम आक्रम्य तिष्ठति [MB - 6.3.12]
>   -A fierce comet rises, afflicting the constellation *Pusya*.

Because Mahabhrata mentions the position of starts and planets in the sky during certain events, researchers are able to find out the dates of the event by analyzing the planetary positions.  So they say that the comet that has been mentioned in the Mahabharata as being seen during the war was Halley's comet. For example, consider the below statement from [this web source](http://www.hindunet.org/hindu_history/ancient/mahabharat/mahab_vartak.html) written by Dr.P.V.Vartak:

> Vyasa has mentioned that at the time of Mahabharat war a big comet was seen just beyond Pushya Nakshtra. There are many comets. Indian Astro- nomical works refer to more than 500 comets, but big comets are very few. Haley's comet is one of the big comets which comes at the regu- lar intervals of 77 years. It was seen in 1910 and 1987. If we add 1910+5561 = 7271. 7271 is divisible completely by 77. Evidently it seems that it was Haley's comet was seen at the Mahabharat War.

Comment: Also, was the comet viewed as a bad/good omen? Or was it just a natural phenomenon of no literal consequence?

Comment: @KharoBangdo yes, the comet was mentioned while describing other bad omens. To suggest that something terrible is going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

[image]th![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PywLY.jp
It’s worth understanding that the 77 year period given for Halley’s Comet in the answer above is completely wrong. The previous researcher (Vartak) for 5561BCE took this date because he thought that 77x 98 = 1986 + 5561 years BUT he couldn’t fathom that the orbital period for Halley’s Comet is 75.32 years.
That comet is actually seen in 3067BCE which turns out is the year of the Mahabharata war and simulations show it at Pushya

Answer (score 1):

In some mantras word **dhumketu** is used which means Comet.

- Rigveda 10:12:2

> देवो देवान्परिभूर्ऋतेन वहा नो हव्यं प्रथमश्चिकित्वान् । **धूमकेतुः** समिधा भाऋजीको मन्द्रो होता नित्यो वाचा यजीयान्॥२॥
>
> devo devân paribhûr r. tena vahâ no havyam prathamas cikitvân |
> **dhûmaketuh**. samidhâ bhârjîko mandro hotâ nityo vâcâ yajîyân ||

- Rigveda 10:4:5

> कूचिज्जायते सनयासु नव्यो वने तस्थौ पलितो **धूमकेतुः** । अस्नातापो वृषभो न प्र वेति सचेतसो यं प्रणयन्त मर्ताः॥५॥
>
> kûcijjâyate sanayâsu navyo vane tasthau palito **dhûmaketuh**. |
> asnâtâpo vr.s.abho na praveti sacetaso yam pran.ayanta martâh. ||